# How to use pymongo command updateUser

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

How do i use pymongo command updateUser ?

I've tried the following commands but with no success:

```
db.command({'updateUser': 'my_user','update':{'$set':{"pwd":"my_pwd"}}})
```

And

```
db.command('updateUser', {"updateUser":"my_user","pwd":"my_pwd"})
```

Returns

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Must specify at least one field to update in updateUser
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python code is executing the MongoDB command "updateUser" on the database side. The command being executed in your code doesn't match the syntax shown in the [updateUser documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/updateUser/).

Try the following:

```
db.command( { updateUser: "<username>",
 pwd: "<cleartext new password>",
 roles: [
  // specify any roles assigned to this user. 
 ]
})
```

The command will completely replace the database user, so any and all role or permission information will need to be specified in the update command.